# Undefine Variable id_gambar codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

if I try to enter data, it can enter the database, but it doesn't display

// GAMBAR
    public function gambar($id_program)
    {
        // panggil model
        $program = $this->program_model->detail($id_program);
        $gambar = $this->program_model->gambar($id_program);

```
    // validasi input
    $valid = $this->form_validation;

    $valid->set_rules('judul_gambar', 'Judul/Nama Gambar', 'required',
        array(  'required'  => '%s harus diisi'));

    if($valid->run()) {
        $config['upload_path']      = './assets/upload/image/';
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']         = '2400'; // KiloByte
        $config['max_width']        = '3000';
        $config['max_height']       = '3000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('gambar')) {

    $data = array(  'title'     => 'Tambah Gambar Program: '.$program->nama_program,
                    'program'   => $program,
                    'gambar'    => $gambar,
                    'error'     => $this->upload->display_errors(),
                    'isi'       => 'admin/program/gambar'
                );      
    $this->load->view('admin/layout/wrapper', $data, FALSE);
}else {

        $upload_data                = array('uploads' =>$this->upload->data());
        // Image Editor
        $config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image']     = './assets/upload/image/'.$upload_data['uploads']['file_name']; 
        $config['new_image']        = './assets/upload/image/thumbs/';
        $config['create_thumb']     = TRUE;
        $config['quality']          = "100%";
        $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;
        $config['width']            = 360; // Pixel
        $config['height']           = 360; // Pixel
        $config['thumb_marker']     = '';
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

    // end create gambar
    $inp = $this->input;

        $data = array(  'id_gambar'         => $id_gambar,
                        'judul_gambar'      => $inp->post('judul_gambar'),
                        'gambar'            => $upload_data['uploads']['file_name'],
                    );
        $this->program_model->tambah_gambar($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', 'Data gambar telah ditambah');
        redirect(base_url('admin/program/gambar/'.$id_program),'refresh');
}}

$data = array(      'title'     => 'Tambah Gambar Program: '.$program->nama_program,
                    'program'   => $program,
                    'gambar'    => $gambar,
                    'isi'       => 'admin/program/gambar'
                );      
$this->load->view('admin/layout/wrapper', $data, FALSE);
}
```

Comment: where is the $id_gambar variable defined?

Comment: $data = array( 'id_gambar'   => $id_gambar,
       'judul_gambar'  => $inp->post('judul_gambar'),
       'gambar'   => $upload_data['uploads']['file_name'],
      );

Comment: could you edit your code with proper indentation, please?

Comment: thanks for all comment. my problem is solved now :D

Answer (score 0):

Is this working for you ?

```
'id_gambar'         => $gambar["id_gambar"];
```

`$id_gambar` is not defined.

Comment: this is the problem, i change this and work :D thank you :D